# Can a function called in NDK c app, defined in a kernel driver?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, android-ndk, linux-device-driver

My problem is that I am trying to build a shared library using a static library.

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libRip
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := src/Rip_api.cpp src/Rip_crypto.cpp

LOCAL_CFLAGS := -DCLR_INTERAPTIV_I7 -DCLR_INTERAPTIV -v

#only include corelockr and rip headers
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/inc/ $(LOCAL_PATH)/include/  $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../hardware/libhardware/include/hardware/

LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog -L$(LOCAL_PATH)/library -lthisis_crypto -lthisis_interaptiv
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES = libsmem.sastra
#test seqr library
#LOCAL_LDFLAGS := -v -L$(LOCAL_PATH)/library -lthisis_crypto  -lthisis_interaptiv

#this option will build static library
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Upon doing this I get some undefined reference errors

```
mmm -B path/to/test/app/android.mk
```

like this

```
I7_Embedded_SDK/corelockr/././src/request.c:494: undefined reference to `function'
```

upon doing nm I see this in this request.o file

```
request.o:
         U function
```

I don't have the source of the main library thisis_crypto, and 
thisis_interaptive, but the wrapper library libRip.so is calling the functions in it. request.o is in library, thisis_interaptive.

That means this function definition is not in the  library. Further I checked the kernel driver ipc.ko, that also is a part of all this work
nm kernel_driver.ko

```
T function
```

that means it is defined here.

1) Is it possible that the app I am trying to build, have some functions, that are using kernel driver.

2) If its possible, how can I build the shared library?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Kernel and user space are two completely separate address spaces. So the short answer is NO :)

Comment: So if in case I see a function undefined in nm of user space library, that means it is really undefined and its a mistake. Also when I build with static library, I don't get any undefined reference errors. Is it possible, that the app may not be using the functions that are undefined in the library, so these functions are stripped from executable?